# CSVデータの日付形式を変換したい

Tags: python, csv

CSVファイルのデータを抽出した日付のデータを変換したいです。
ただ下記のコードで試してみましたが、何も変化がないです。
日付の形式を変換するにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

CSVのデータ

```
A       B     C         
アメリカ  1234  2020/01/02 　 
カナダ　 1234　2020/02/03
```

CSVのデータ→形式を変換後

```
A       B     C         
アメリカ  1234  2020-01-02 　→"/"→"-"に変換
カナダ　 1234　2020-02-03
```

コード

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=str, encoding='utf_8_sig')
df2 =df.replace("-", "/")
print(df2)
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問のコードはエラーになりませんか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
失礼しました。'df2 =df.replace("-", "/")'に修正しました。
こちら実行しても変換ないです。

Comment: `replace` を使うのであれば `regex=True` とする必要があります。`df.replace({'/': '-'}, regex=True)`

Comment: 重複？ [文字列の一部となっている単語の置き換え](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49042/)

Comment: `df.replace({'/': '-'}, regex=True)`こちらの方法で出来ました。いつもありがとうございます。`regex=True`追加しないといけないですね

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの方法で解決できました。

`replace` を使う時に `regex=True` を追加する必要があります。
詳しくは下記のリンクを参考にしました。

[[Python] pandasのDataFrameで部分一致で文字列を置換](https://it-ojisan.tokyo/pandas-replace-regex/)

**コード:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=str, encoding='utf_8_sig')
df2 =df.replace({'/': '-'}, regex=True)
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`datetime` を使用して変換しました！

参考サイト
https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-datetime-timestamp/

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=str, encoding='utf_8_sig')
df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])
df
```